# Relationship between full row rank and span

Tags: linear-algebra

If a m x n matrix has full row rank, is it safe to assume that the columns of A span R^m because there is a pivot position in every row?

Comment: Yes.  It's not because there are pivots in each row (there are only pivots in a row reduced matrix), but because $(1)$ row rank = column rank (meaning the number of linearly independent rows = the number of linearly independent columns), $(2)$ full row rank means that the rows are linearly independent, $(3)$ there are $m$ rows, and $(4)$ each column is a member of $\Bbb R^m$.  Put those all together and you can $\operatorname{col}(A) = \Bbb R^m$.

Comment: Oh okay thanks.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Full row rank also implies that the dimension of the left null space  is 0? Since its dimension is m-r and there are m rows. Is there any significance to that?

Comment: You're correct.  The rank-nullity theorem implies that $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \dim(\operatorname{lnull}(A)) = m$.  Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = m$, the left null space is the trivial space.  The only significance I can think of that hasn't already been mentioned is that the space of $1\times m$ row vectors (which is $m$-dimensional) will get mapped to an $m$-dimensional space by this matrix.